# Deserializing json response to custom enum value in java

Tags: java, jackson, fasterxml

I am trying to deserialize a JSON response with custom enum values, but instead of mapping with the custom value, the enum is being set with its ordinal value. I have searched a lot and I can not figure out what I am doing wrong. Any help would be great.

The response is

```
{"id":12, "status":1}
```

Corresponding enum object and enum is

```
public class Car {
   int id;
   CarStatus status;
}


public enum CarStatus {
    
    READY(1),
    WAITING(2);

    private int value;

    CarStatus(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @JsonValue
    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }

}
```

The status is set to *WAITING*, but I expect it to be set to *READY*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your enum miss @JsonCreator

try like this:

```
public enum CarStatus {
    
    READY(1),
    WAITING(2);

    private int value;

    CarStatus(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @JsonValue
    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    @JsonCreator
    public static CarStatus getItem(int code){
        for(CarStatus item : values()){
            if(item.getValue() == code){
                return item;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

you can see my code in github: https://github.com/onemaomao/java-common-mistakes/tree/master/src/main/java/org/geekbang/time/questions/stackoverflow/reslove/q1

Comment: Enumeration is not recommended for transport across services because of versioning issues and because deserialization is complex and error-prone when it comes to serialization. Therefore, I only recommend using enumerations within inner programs.

Answer (score 0):

This seems so be a known problem for enums when using an integer in combination with only a `@JsonValue` annotation. There are open issues on Github which refer to this (e.g. [1](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/2754) and [2](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/1850)) which are currently planned for version 2.13.

In the meantime, you can solve this by adding a `@JsonCreator` which returns the corresponding `CarStatus`:

```java
public enum CarStatus {

    READY(1),
    WAITING(2);

    private final int value;

    CarStatus(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @JsonValue
    public int getValue() {
        return this.value;
    }

    @JsonCreator
    public static CarStatus getByValue(int value) {
        for (CarStatus status : values()) {
            if (status.value == value) {
                return status;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

---

*Code to test:*

```java
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

Car original = new Car();
original.setId(45);
original.setStatus(CarStatus.READY);

String json = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(original);

Car reconstruction = objectMapper.readValue(json, Car.class);

System.out.println(json);
System.out.println(reconstruction.getStatus());
```

*Output:*

```
{"id":45,"status":1}
READY
```